# Javascript check given date is greater than current date in (d/m/yyyy) date format shows false

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

In database my date is stored in D/M/YYYY format eq:(7/1/2021)

```
var todayDate = (
 new Date().getDate() +
  "/" +
  (new Date().getMonth() + 1) +
  "/" +
  new Date().getFullYear()
);
 console.log(todayDate);
```

shows current date as 14/1/2021
when i compare to know which date is greater it  shows false

```
console.log(todayDate > date);// date stored in database(7/1/2021)
```

can anyone please solve this and thanks in advance

Comment: Why not comparing getTime() which represent the mili-seconds since epoch instead of a **string** formatted date comparison? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't compare date strings using ">" operator. if its a string it's comparing them alphabetically.

Instead use `date.getTime()` to compare.

also, just use toLocalDateString() for date stings, instead of trying to re-invent the wheel yourself.

```
var todayDate = (new Date().toLocalDateString());
console.log(todayDate);
```

Comment: Now i have stored dates as D/M/YYYY how will i compare now. new.Date().toLocalDateString() gives date in MM/DD/YYYY format. I wanted the date in D/M/YYYY formate.

Comment: How to compare dates using date.getTime() to compare date in my code

Comment: simply create a function that converts your D/M/YYYY string into a date object. then use .getTime() to compare to other dates. The important thing is converting your data into date objects and not comparing them as strings.